# Fatal error: Call to a member function isPathAllowed() on a non-object in /Filter.php on line 498

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I ran into an issue while upgrading magento from version 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isPathAllowed() on a non-object
>   in
>   /magento/var/cache/ew/files/7e/e0/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
>   on line 498

Can any one guide me how i can solve this problem
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Refresh magento cache and also third party extension cache or disable it and check

Comment: @RohitKundale Cache is disabled. and renamed the cache folder too

Comment: I think you have installed third party cache extension. Please disable all local extension and then check

Comment: disable compilation if enabled

Comment: @Haris Please refresh your extendware cache. i think in your system `http://www.extendware.com/magento-full-page-cache.html`  extension is installed

Comment: @RohitKundale, no extendware cache is not installed but  Extendware_EWImageOpt.xml
Extendware_EWMinify.xml are installed there

Comment: Disable that extension from `app/etc/modules/` and check is there is error coming

Comment: @RohitKundale thanks, disabling extensions solved the problem. now I will have to find the bug, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the list of extension that are causing problem in magento `SUPEE-6788 / Magento 1.9.2.2 / EE 1.14.2.2`

Extensions that will break with `SUPEE-6788 / Magento 1.9.2.2 / EE 1.14.2.2`

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0
```

check if your installed extension are in this list disabled that will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks disabling Extendware_EWImageOpt solved the problem for now